# How can i resolve the css warnings for browser specific selectors in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Just include bootstrap.js and css files and open google chrome's console, there are a lot of "Invalid CSS property xxx" outputs, I haven't seen this before on bootstrap 2.3.2

I've copied the warnings below. They crowd my console:

```
Invalid CSS selector: button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner (12:59:57:616 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap.min.css:9
Invalid CSS selector: .form-control:-moz-placeholder (12:59:57:630 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap.min.css:9
Invalid CSS selector: .form-control::-moz-placeholder (12:59:57:631 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap.min.css:9
Invalid CSS selector: .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder (12:59:57:661 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap.min.css:9
Invalid CSS property name: -webkit-overflow-scrolling (12:59:57:662 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap.min.css:9
Invalid CSS property value: transform .3s ease-out (12:59:57:663 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap.min.css:9
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,color-stop(rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0),color-stop(rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%)) (12:59:57:664 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap.min.css:9
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,color-stop(rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 0),color-stop(rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%)) (12:59:57:670 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap.min.css:9
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,0%,#e6e6e6,100%) (12:59:57:674 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#428bca,0%,#3071a9,100%) (12:59:57:675 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#5cb85c,0%,#449d44,100%) (12:59:57:683 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f0ad4e,0%,#ec971f,100%) (12:59:57:684 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#d9534f,0%,#c9302c,100%) (12:59:57:684 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#5bc0de,0%,#31b0d5,100%) (12:59:57:685 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#428bca,0%,#357ebd,100%) (12:59:57:685 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,0%,#f8f8f8,100%) (12:59:57:691 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#3c3c3c,0%,#222,100%) (12:59:57:692 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#dff0d8,0%,#c8e5bc,100%) (12:59:57:693 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#d9edf7,0%,#b9def0,100%) (12:59:57:694 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fcf8e3,0%,#f8efc0,100%) (12:59:57:694 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f2dede,0%,#e7c3c3,100%) (12:59:57:695 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#ebebeb,0%,#f5f5f5,100%) (12:59:57:696 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#428bca,0%,#3071a9,100%) (12:59:57:696 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#5cb85c,0%,#449d44,100%) (12:59:57:697 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#5bc0de,0%,#31b0d5,100%) (12:59:57:701 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f0ad4e,0%,#ec971f,100%) (12:59:57:701 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#d9534f,0%,#c9302c,100%) (12:59:57:702 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#428bca,0%,#3278b3,100%) (12:59:57:702 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,0%,#e8e8e8,100%) (12:59:57:703 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#428bca,0%,#357ebd,100%) (12:59:57:704 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#dff0d8,0%,#d0e9c6,100%) (12:59:57:704 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#d9edf7,0%,#c4e3f3,100%) (12:59:57:705 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fcf8e3,0%,#faf2cc,100%) (12:59:57:705 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f2dede,0%,#ebcccc,100%) (12:59:57:706 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#e8e8e8,0%,#f5f5f5,100%) (12:59:57:707 | warning, css)
  at public_html/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css:1
```

(
Reformatting the code, stackoverflow asked me to add more details in description. I hit the same issue and this is the most relevant question in google search results, hopefully someone has a solution.
)

Comment: Can you edit your question so it's a bit more specific?  This is a useful question.  What's happening is you have browser-specific css extensions being used, and they don't apply and they're showing up as warnings.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl, I hit the same issue, so edited the question, hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most important thing to note is that Chrome is telling you that *it* thinks those CSS selectors are invalid. That does not, however, mean they're inherently and/or universally invalid or that you've erred in some way.

**Two foundational coding points:**

1. Browsers (usually) ignore most things they don't understand and that generally goes for CSS as well.
2. While browsers try to adhere to the core specifications, when it comes to CSS they're notorious for having their own CSS attributes for certain things, especially when supporting legacy browsers.

So, with those two things in mind, CSS writers who have a large, varied browser base to support (e.g., Twitter Bootstrap) will throw in all the CSS selectors and such for all browsers they intend to support, knowing that IE will ignore selectors supported by WebKit-based browsers, and Chrome will ignore IE-specifics, and so on.

Here's a related article on this technique when handling gradients: [CSS3 Linear Gradient Syntax Breakdown](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-linear-gradient-syntax/).

**Another reason you might be seeing the warning recently is that**

- [Chrome 27 was the last version to support WebKit](http://www.sitepoint.com/chrome-27-whats-new/).

So if you see a CSS warning for "-webkit-overflow-scrolling" and if you're using Chrome 28 or later then I can see why you'd start seeing WebKit-related CSS warnings. (I didn't regression test with pre- and post-WebKit versions of Chrome to 100% confirm this, but my Geek Intuition™ is 90% confident that's what is going on here).

Again, I wouldn't worry about it, so long as what you're seeing is what you're expecting. Be sure to test with a WebKit-based browser to make sure the WebKit-targeted code works as expected, too.

Comment: Thanks Phil.  I just wish I could filter or turn off these warnings in my netbeans console so that I don't miss the more useful errors that come through.  I can easily turn off warnings in chrome, but not in my integrated netbeans.

Comment: You're welcome.  I did a little research and it looks like *many* NetBeans users are irritated by the "warnings" (which looks like it should be "info" since a warning is unjustified), and one those grounds some have even submitted it as a bug report.  BTW, my answer was a satisfactory answer to your question, could you mark it as an accepted answer?  This thread still shows as no accepted answer posted and I'd appreciate the bump :-)  Thanks.