# How to fix "invalid CSS property declaration" in Safari?

Tags: html, css

I bought a theme from Themeforest, and notice the theme is not working well in Safari 9 and iOS. The theme does not render CSS completely and throws some messages **"invalid CSS property declaration at: 0"** to the CSS below:

```
@-webkit-keyframes border-pulse-2 {
  0% {
    border-width: 3px
  }
  33.33333% {
    border-width: 3px
  }
  66.66666% {
    border-width: 23px
  }
  100% {
    border-width: 23px
  }
}
```

There are a few of more lines in the same CSS file showing the same issues.

The theme has no problem on Chrome and Firefix and the page can be shown correctly.

Comment: Have you looked at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471468/how-can-i-resolve-the-css-warnings-for-browser-specific-selectors-in-bootstrap-3

Comment: The link given is not on Safari. I have no issues with Chrome and Firefox except Safari.

Comment: Try to look for unneeded ; in the keyframe declaration. for example make sure you don't have something like: 100% { border-width: 32px; };} - note the semicolon between the 2 }

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari

Comment: You might want to see if it's related to the CSS intentionally using the "Star hack" to make it support on older version of IE.  Can you confirm it is really this that is affecting Safari 9 on iOS though?  Usually it has no effect if it's the reason I mentioned here.

Answer (score -2):

Be sure there are not semicolons between brackets

Wrong, there are semicolons between brackets **};**

```
@-webkit-keyframes border-pulse-2 {
  0% {
    border-width: 3px;
  };
  33.33333% {
    border-width: 3px;
  };
  66.66666% {
    border-width: 23px;
  };
  100% {
    border-width: 23px;
  };
}
```

Right, there are not semicolons between brackets

```
@-webkit-keyframes border-pulse-2 {
  0% {
    border-width: 3px;
  }
  33.33333% {
    border-width: 3px;
  }
  66.66666% {
    border-width: 23px;
  }
  100% {
    border-width: 23px;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with not having semicolons after lone declarations in each declaration block. The CSS given in the question is fine and should be recognized by any WebKit-compatible browser that supports animations.

Comment: The w3 CSS validator return a sintaxis error with semicolons after declaration block.  https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input 
The browsers ignore this error, but safari for iOS don't. I experience this problem with my website. Firefox, Chrome, Safari even IE works fine but safari and chrome for iOS give a headache

Comment: I'm not talking about semicolons following declaration blocks, I'm talking about semicolons following the last declaration *inside* a declaration block. Your first example, that you say is wrong, is in fact not wrong.

Comment: You are  right. My mistake. I'll edit the answer. Thanks for the feedback